# When Should I Use Light and Dense Zoning?

Tags: simcity-2000

I've been wondering when I should use light zoning, and when I should use dense zoning. Some people say I should start small, but I see some people go straight for dense zoning. What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Light zones are taxed less than dense zoning but also generate less population growth, pollution and crime. Light zoning is also cheaper to place than dense zoning.

Conversely, dense zones generate more tax and population growth but cost more to place.

In practice, there isn't a huge difference between light and dense, which is likely why you've heard people suggesting just going straight for dense zoning.

Note that when upgrading zoning, placing a dense zone over a light zone will still charge you the full price for the dense zone.